# How to change the bottom navigation bar items based on a condition in Flutter

Tags: flutter, bottomnavigationview

I have a list of bottom nav bar items: [A, B, C, D]. I want to change this list depending on a condition X.

For example: When the user is logged out, user has the list mentioned [A,B,C,D]. But when the user logs in, the bottom nav bar item list needs to change to [A, B, C, E]. I add and remove the items from the list when the condition X is changed at runtime. However this seems quite incorrect to me and I am not sure if this is the way to go about this issue.

Sometimes there is the issue where the list does not update and stays [A,B,C,D]. Should I have two separate lists for the items perhaps?

Any help is appreciated, thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply make a function of return type List.

```
List navBarItems (){

  if(your condition X){

    return ["item1","item2","item3"];
  }else{
    return ["item1","item2"];
  }

}
```

Then place it in bottom nav bar items: navBarItems().
or simply

```
bottomnavbaritems:(condition X)?["item1","item2","item3"]: ["item1","item2"];
```

And use setState() to change the conditions.