# Flutter Bottom Navigation Bar with conditions

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I want to have a bottom navigation bar, and in the list of widgets i want to have the different screens. But to show the working screen or not i have var isWorking = prefs.getString('isWorking'), and i want that if isWorking == null to return WorkingScreen else StopWorkingScreen. From doing my research i think i have to use Future Builder, but if someone can demostrate on how to fix this issue than ill highly appreciate it. And btw im trying to have the same bottom navigation bar for WorkingScreen() and StopWorkingScreen(), so if the user is isWorking != null it will show the StopWorkingScreen(), and the bottom navigation bar at the bottom too, same with the WorkingScreen(), so the screens that are gonna be with the bottom navigation bars are WorkingScreen(), StopWorkingScreen(), ReportScreen(), ProfileScreen(), EditProfileScreen. But when the user presses the home bottom navy button it will check if the user is working or not and will show the screen. But the EditProfileScreen() is not gonna have its own bottom naby bar since is a part of the ProfileScreen so its just gonan have the same bottom navy bar as the Profile Screen. So (WorkingScreen(), StopWorkingScreen()) same bottom navy bar, (ReportsScreen()) navy second navy var, and the third is (ProfileScreen() and  EditProfileScreen()) having the same bottom navy bar

```
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {

  Future<Widget> isUserWorking () async{
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var isWorking = prefs.getString('isWorking');
    if(isWorking == null){
      return const WorkingScreen();
    } else{
      return const StopWorkingScreen();
    }
  },
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  static const TextStyle optionStyle =
  TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
  static List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    isUserWorking(), // this is what im trying to do but getting error
    ReportsScreen(),
    ProfileScreen(),
  ];

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('BottomNavigationBar Sample'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.business),
            label: 'Business',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.school),
            label: 'School',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can plug your future into a `FutureBuilder` like this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class IsUserWorking extends StatelessWidget {
  const IsUserWorking({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<SharedPreferences>(
      future: SharedPreferences.getInstance(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        final isWorking = snapshot.data?.getString('isWorking');
        if(isWorking == null){
          return const WorkingScreen();
        } else{
        return const StopWorkingScreen();
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

A simple google search also gave me this, [How to change the bottom navigation bar items based on a condition in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60390783/how-to-change-the-bottom-navigation-bar-items-based-on-a-condition-in-flutter)